# Implementing listview with scrollable views and view caching

Tags: android, listview, horizontalscrollview

I'm on a research to design a `ListView` with horizontal scroll of views - something like in the facebook app.

I also need to implement a caching for the horizontally scrollable views.

Some of the options I can think of are:

- Horizontal scroll view items.
- A `ViewPager` which I understand is not quite good for this task.

What would be my way to go on this?

I've read some StackOverflow questions and am still researching but none of what I read so far also implement caching for the scrolled horizontal views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use two `RecyclerView`s which are nested. The backing data is a two dimensional array as the layout is two-dimensional. The outer `RecyclerView` passes the data for the inner `RecyclerView` when the `onBindViewHolder` of the adapter is called. Additionally you may also use different layouts or `ViewHolder` respectively if the inner view consists only of a single item and does not require horizontal scrolling.

Some references about implementing `RecyclerView`s

Here: http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-1-fundamentals-for-listview-experts/

Here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

and here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: Thanks for the references (I've read them all before and familiar with recycleView) but this doesn't quite answer the question. As far as I know and can tell from this docs - recycleView support vertical or horizontal scrolling. I need regular vertical scrolling with each list item being horizontal scrolled.

Comment: In this case, you probably should have two `RecyclerView`s which are nested. The inner view will scroll horizontally, the outer view scrolls vertically. I understood, that in your case your backing data is a two-dimensional array, right?

Comment: My backing data size will vary. One item in the list might be just a simple item with no need for horizontal scrolling at all. Another item might have 10 horizontal scrolled views and another item might have just 3.

Comment: You think I should have a recycle view that each item it holds is another recycleView?

Comment: facebook's app timeline is a perfect example of what I'm looking for

Comment: Yes, your backing data array should be two dimensional as your layout is two-dimensional. If you have only one item in the inner array, you will only draw one item in the inner view. The outer view passes the inner backing array when `OuterRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder()` is called. Additionally, you may also try to create different layouts for instance when you only have a single view. In this case you must override `getItemViewType` where you return either the nested RecyclerView or the SingleItemView

Comment: I'm gonna try implementing a simple demo of it using static arrays of data. Hopefully this will work for me

Comment: I've just implemented this suggestion - an inner recycler view. Please post a new answer and I will choose it as the solution

Comment: I edited my answer according to my previous comment. Glad, that it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/) will help you. You can use caching while scrolling. For example if you load images with horizontal scroll bar, you could use picasso library for catching and loading images.

Comment: Thank you chain. I've read about this library here - http://profi.co/android-horizontal-list-view-library-with-item-scroll/   right before I posted this question and this might be a solution that I'm exploring. Do you know of any app that uses this lib which I can check to see if it does sort of what I want?

Comment: you first read his blog http://lucasr.org/2014/07/31/the-new-twowayview/ . and then decide you can able to do this or not. You have to customise this, you can't get exact sample or app. Instead of searching you can implement.

Answer (score 0):

Dont think big we have some library that will do what you want below listed some of them

https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView

https://github.com/EmirWeb/parchment

https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView

any one this link will help you i belive

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Implementing-a-Horizontal-ListView-Guide

https://www.airpair.com/android/horizontal-image-galleries-android-studio

Comment: Hi yosi is that helpful or you are facing any problems

Comment: Hi these are always helpful but what this show are how to create a listview which is horizontally scrolling. What I needed was both horizontal and vertical scroll